# How to load all JqueryMobile internal pages properly after linking from 1st HTML file to 2nd?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile, dom, jquery-mobile-ajax

I'm having trouble with a simple Jquerymobile navigation setup.

I have 3 HTML/PHP files that each contain a multiple Jquerymobile pages. I have created simple code as shown below - each file has the same code (except for the list view links).

When I load file1.php I can use the navigation bar to switch from Page 1 to Page 2.
When I click a link to file2.php it loads on Page 1 (i.e. file1.php#Page1. However, when I try to navigate to Page 2, it loads file1.php#Page2 instead of file2.php#Page1 ..

I presume I have done something wrong regarding loading the page properly into the DOM - but I'm not sure how to fix it - any help would be greatly appreciated.

(note header.php just includes all necessary cs and javascript for jquerymobile)

```
<?php 
require_once("header.php");
?>
<body>

    <!-- This is the first page -->
    <div id="page1" data-role="page">
        <header data-role="header">
            <h1>Page1</h1>
        </header>
        <div data-role="navbar">
             <ul>
                <li><a href="#page1" data-transition="slide" class="ui-btn-b">Page1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#page2">Page2</a></li>
            </ul><br>
        </div>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="file1.php">Link to first HTML page</a></li>
            <li><a href="file3.php">Link to third HTML page</a></li>
          </ul>
    </div>

    <!-- This is the second page -->
    <div id="page2" data-role="page">
        <header data-role="header">
            <h1>Page2</h1>
        </header>
        <div data-role="navbar">
             <ul>
                <li><a href="#page1">Page1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#page2" data-transition="slide" class="ui-btn-b">Page2</a></li>
            </ul><br>
        </div>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="file1.php">Link to first HTML page</a></li>
            <li><a href="file3.php">Link to third HTML page</a></li>
          </ul>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When using _Single page model_ each _page_ should be in a separate file. jQM loads first _page_ div in each file and neglects the rest. First loaded page can have more than one _page_ div, but the rest of files no.

Comment: When I switch to file2.php from file1.php and reload it, everything works properly (on page2). Is it not possible to force a full load of file2.php when it is linked from file1.php?

Comment: When you reload file2.php, it becomes first page and all pages inside it are accessible. There are some plugins for this, but instead of using plugins, load extra pages as external ones. jQM neglects other pages to avoid _history_ conflict between pages.

Comment: OK - I fixed the problem using data-ajax="false"